# Is there any way to update a lists of lists with only the specified element?

Tags: python, list

is there any way to update a *lists of lists* (in this case, 4) with only the specified element?
For example:

```py
list1 = [['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']]
list2 = [['b', 'b', 'a', 'c'], ['b', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
list3 = [['c', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['b', 'a', 'b', 'b']]
list4 = [['c', 'a', 'a', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a', 'b']]
```

If I want to update *list1* with the string **'b'**, it should output:

> [[b, b, b, c], [b, a, b, b]]

So, from the ***first list inside the list1***, the first element, **'a'**, is replaced by **'b'** as other list(s) contains the string **'b'** (in this case, list2). However, the last element, **'c'** did not get updated as no lists contain the string **'b'**.

I've tried nesting multiple for loop, however that is extremely inefficient.

```py
for list in list1:
  for i in list:
      if i != 'b':
          for list in list2:
              for j in list:
                  if j == b:
                      i = 'b'
```

What I want to archive is: If there is 'b' in other lists, update the element in list1 to be 'b'

Comment: Between the example and the explanation I'm still lost. Please show either a better breakdown or some example code that you have tried. Whatever you are trying to do is possible but it's hard to distinguish what it is you want.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to achieve. could you please post a few more example input/output pairs or a more specific explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate through the arrays with `enumerate` and see if any of the other lists contain a specified element (in your case, `'b'`), updating if any of them do.

```py
for v, a in enumerate(list1):
    for v1, b in enumerate(a):
        if 'b' in [i[v][v1] for i in [list2, list3, list4]]:
            list1[v][v1] = 'b'
```